How can I reduce the size of my nest.js Docker container built with a multi-stage Dockerfile?
I am currently using a multi-stage Dockerfile to build and run a Node.js application. The final container size is approximately 600 MB, and I would like to reduce it further. Here's my current Dockerfile:
# Build stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
Add 
RUN npm install --cache /npm-cache

# Runtime stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

I suspect there are optimizations I could make, such as reducing the size of the build artifacts or excluding unnecessary files. How can I reduce the container size while ensuring the app functions correctly?

Does it help to use a smaller base image, as in What is the difference between node images for Docker and when to use which?  Does it help to only install production dependencies, as in How can I reduce my Docker Image size for deployment?
